wave vector and frquency dependent Dielectric function using DFT
In the following equation, $S(\omega)$ is a transmission function, $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ are real and imaginary dielectric functions respectively. If we notice the equation carefully, we need $\epsilon (q, \omega)$ since the summation includes all the q points in the 1st BZ.
$S(\omega) = \frac{1}{A} \sum_{q \in \text{1BZ}} \frac{4e^{-2qd} \, \text{Im}\left[\epsilon_1^{-1}(q, \omega)\right]_{00} \, \text{Im}\left[\epsilon_2^{-1}(q, \omega)\right]_{00}}{\left|1 - e^{-2qd} \left[\left(\epsilon_1^{-1}(q, \omega)\right)_{00} - 1\right] \left[\left(\epsilon_2^{-1}(q, \omega)\right)_{00} - 1\right]\right|^2}$
Normally if I do DFT using Quantum Espresso, I would get the dielectric function ($\epsilon$) over frequency ($\omega$) ranges. Are there anyway I would get dielectric function $\epsilon(\omega)$ at each q point?
The link of the paper related to the equation (9) (https://journals.aps.org/prapplied/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevApplied.14.024080)
Thank you in advance for your time.
